# PAYPAL intégration with Laravel

Tags: laravel, paypal

Hello guys I just integrated Paypal with a developer account and it works well with Count Test.
However I would like to integrate it into a professional account.
My question is are the same procedure that we must apply
In other words, create an application in the pros account, retrieve identifiers (customer ID and secret key) and configure it with our application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Obtain the client-id and secret from the 'Live' tab of a Rest APP in https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications
- Ensure that when using this client-id and secret, you communicate with `api(-m).paypal.com` endpoints, not `api*.sandbox.paypal.com`